# Multithreading: How can we do Time Slicing using Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, threadpool

Is it possible to do Time Slicing using Java using In-bult java classes?

When searched on internet i am getting following kind of definitions only:

> Time slicing is a term which is usually associated with the processor and operating system ...
>       what it means is ... When you have many processes running by an operating system then each process has to get 
>       a chance to run ..that is each of the process should get the processor for particular time.....so now if you have 
>       3 processes running eg- p0,p1,p2 then now p0 can run for a time of 5 ms then comes turn for p1 then for p2.....
>       thus you are giving some time called as timeslice to each of the process that has to run by the processor.....
>       Thus there are different algorithms which exists for these processes(depeneds on the operating System) 
>       to run on a processor.....

I am getting this question in Java Interview questions. But not able to get any Java Code example related to same.

Is Time Slicing merely concept of Operating System or is there any practical usage to show using Java Programming? Can someone please share example for same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` then start `n + 1` threads. By definition, if `n + 1` threads are running on `n` cores then time slicing is occurring. Practical usage, you need to run `n + 1` threads and only have `n` cpu cores.

Comment: Thanks @Elliit Frishch

I have available Processors as 4. I will start 5 Threads then Time Slicing is occurring in Operating system by default and has nothing to deal with Program. I mean we cant say it can be handled through program i.e we assign time to particular thread ourselves. (underneath also timeslicing is running)

Comment: Java has no mechanism for scheduling threads; Java threads are backed by native threads and native threads are scheduled by the operating system.